# How do I rename Sheet in Excel using TinyButStrong Excel?

Tags: php, excel, xlsx, opentbs, tinybutstrong

I have a TBS Excel template with numerous sheets.  I want to rename each sheet to match a variable that is going to be put into cell A2.  I know Excel will not allow special characters in table names, so I can not use a square brackets to set a TBS variable.

Is there a way to change the sheet names programatically either using TinyButStrong Excel or PHP (note: PHP Excel is not an option in this environment)?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Don't you mean sheet names instead of table names ?

Comment: Tiny But Strong appears to refer to them as Tables

Comment: I don't think so. The inner XML may use some « table » items but the feature talks about Sheet.

Answer (score 0):

For now (OpenTBS version 1.9.11) there is no special feature for renaming a sheet in an XLSX workbook.

Nevertheless, you can open the sub-file 'xl/workbook.xml' and replace the the old sheet name by the new one knowing that the sheet name is stored in a `name` attribute.

XSLX example:

```
<sheet name="My old sheet" sheetId="1" r:id="rId1"/>
```

PHP code:

```
$TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_SELECT_FILE, 'xl/workbook.xml');
$TBS->Source = str_replace('name="My old sheet"', 'name="My new sheet"', $TBS->Source);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the titles of the tabs are not appearing in the $TBS->Source, so they can't be changed that way.  Trying it on xlsx files also doesn't work because it's binary data.